# What is the difference between single quotes and double quotes in these two functions?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between single quotes and double quotes in these two functions? After I swap the two symbols, it can run normally. At the same time, I also want to know how to check this error through the content in the screenshot. The content is an overloaded function that matches the parameter list. How can I tell what type of parameter it is through the content inside?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    
    void combine(std::string &name, const std::string &before, const std::string &later)
    {
    
        name.insert(name.begin(), 1, " ");
        name.insert(name.begin(), before.begin(), before.end());
        name.append(' ');
        name.append(later.begin(), later.end());
    }
    int main()
    {
        std::string s = "qwer";
        combine(s, "333", "55-");
        std::cout << s;
    }
```

Comment: It's the same as always in C++. Single quotes are character-literals while double quotes denote string-literals.

Comment: You avoid mistakes here by looking at a reference for these functions before using them to see whether they expect a string or just a character: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single-quote means for one-character. Can be used in type `char`

Double-quotes means for a string. Can be used in type `char[]` or `string`, ...

Comment: The type of an ordinary string literal is array of `const char`, not array of `char` and also not `std::string`.

Comment: `char` is also not the only type for these literals. You can also do `int x = 'abcd'`, for example.

Comment: That's not the main point. He is asking about the main differences between single and double quotes in these two functions.